# How to Get a Search to Return Multiple Selections from Dropdown on Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, search, razor-pages, dropdownbox

I have a razor page search that has a beginning and ending date range plus a dropdown where the user can select one (or MORE) municipalities. I am obviously missing something in my code setup, but I am not sure what.

The date range works great, but when I add the dropdown for selecting the municipalities, the search only returns the first municipality of the ones selected.

Here is my .cs:

```
using Referrals.Data;
using Referrals.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Referrals.Pages.Reports.AllMunisListing;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Referral> Results { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<Municipality> DisplayRefMunis { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<string> searchmuni { get; set; }

    public string DateReceivedSort { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Results = _db.Referral.ToList();

        await _db.Municipality.Select(a => a.Name).ToListAsync();
        DisplayRefMunis = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string searchmuni, string sortOrder)
    {
        
        Results = (from x in _db.Referral where (x.DateReceived >= startdate) && (x.DateReceived <= enddate) && x.RefMunicipality.Contains(searchmuni.ToString()) select x).ToList();

        DateReceivedSort = sortOrder == "DateReceived_Asc_Sort" ? "DateReceived_Desc_Sort" : "DateReceived_Asc_Sort";

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "DateReceived_Asc_Sort":
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.DateReceived);
                break;
            case "DateReceived_Desc_Sort":
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateReceived);
                break;
            default:
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.DateReceived);
                break;
        }

        DisplayRefMunis = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

        TempData["StartDate"] = startdate.ToShortDateString();
        TempData["EndDate"] = enddate.ToShortDateString();
        TempData["SearchMuni"] = searchmuni;
        return Page();
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant part of my view:

```
@page
@model Referrals.Pages.Reports.AllMunisListing.IndexModel

<partial name="_Notification" />

<div id="" class="container p-3">


    <br /><br />

    <form asp-page="./Index" method="post">
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <p>
                <table id="ReferralTable" class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                            Select Beginning Date Received: <input type="date" name="startdate" value="" /> and Ending Date Received: <input type="date" name="enddate" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="ReferralTable" class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">
                            Select Municipality(ities):
                            <select asp-for="@Model.searchmuni" name="searchmuni" id="Select1" style="width: 250px" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayRefMunis.OrderBy(x => x.Id),"Name", "Name"))" multiple="multiple"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Municipality(ies)---</option></select>
                        </td>
                        <td width="80%">
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" />
                            <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-link mx-2">Return to Full List</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="AllMunisListing"class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-25">
                <h4 class="text-primary" align="center">@TempData["StartDate"] through @TempData["EndDate"]</h4>
                <h4 class="text-primary" align="center">@TempData["SearchMuni"]</h4>
            </div>
```

I am thinking the issue lies here:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string searchmuni, string sortOrder)
```

And here:

```
Results = (from x in _db.Referral where (x.DateReceived >= startdate) && (x.DateReceived <= enddate) && x.RefMunicipality.Contains(searchmuni.ToString()) select x).ToList();
```

I just don't know what it SHOULD be.

Any guidance as to what piece is missing and where it should go is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Add the `multiple` attribute to the `select` element and bind it to a collection of whatever type is appropriate for your values: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists#enabling-multiple-selections

Comment: I have updated my code above to reflect the addtion of the multiple="multiple" attribute. I also pointed the asp-for to my IEnumerable, DisplayRefMunis. But I don't understand this. I have the asp-items set to DisplayRefMunis. Can both of these be the same? The page still returns only the first municipality selected. I don't want to chenge those values, only use them for returning search results.

Comment: I am confused about why don't you use `[BindProperty]` attribute in Razor Page, In your dropdown list, `Asp-for` will generate name and id attribute automatically, You don't need to to specify them by yourself. Your drop down list is `multiple` , It will return list<T>, But you seems to just  use `string searchmuni` to accept it.

Comment: @Xinran Shen. Thank you for your demo. I am still a beginner at this and have no formal training. What I have learned is from googling, videos and asking questions. I have made your changes to 'List', but my page still only returns the first municipality. I am fairly certain this is because of my 'OnPost' and my 'Results ='. I do not know what syntax to use to return the multiple values. Can you please explain? I have tried List, but get errors.

Comment: @MelB, That's OK, Razor Page is a little different from MVC, I recommand you to refer this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) first. In my demo, I create a `List<string> searchmuni` proeprty to receive the selected values, Then I use `asp-for` to specify this property, When you submit this form, The selected value will be bind to this property.

Comment: @XinranShen. Haha. That link is to one of the main documents I try to learn from. Unfortunately, I don't know enough to understand all of what it means yet. I have update the code above to what I have tried, but this does not work.

Comment: Hi @MelB, In razor page, you don't need to add parameter in OnPost() action, After you add `[BindProperty]` to your property, When you use `asp-for` to specify this property, After you submit the form, The value will be bind to this property automatically. So here remove all parameters in your `OnPost()` and add related property like: '[BindProperty] public DateTime startdate {get;set;} ...'

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple demo to achieve multiple select in dropdown list. hope it can give you some help.

```
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Municipality> DisplayRefMunis { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<string> searchmuni { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // For testing, I just hard code here
            DisplayRefMunis = new List<Municipality>() {
                new Municipality()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "AAAAA"
                },
                new Municipality()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "BBBB"
                },
                new Municipality()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "CCCC"
                },
                new Municipality()
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    Name = "DDDD"
                },

            };
        }
```

**Views**

```
@page
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<form method="post">
    Select Municipality(ities):
    <select asp-for="@Model.searchmuni" style="width: 250px" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayRefMunis.OrderBy(x => x.Id),"Name", "Name"))" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Municipality(ies)---</option>
    </select>

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Gif Demo

[image]